# Murmur3 Hash Algorithm Used in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to reproduce the Murmur3 hashing in Cassandra. Does anyone know how to get at the actual hash values used in the row keys? I just need some key - hash value pairs from my data to check that my implementation of the hashing is correct.

Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ask Cassandra! Insert some data in your table. Afterwards, you can use the token function in a select query to get the used token values. For example:

```
select token(id), id from myTable;
```

A composite partition key is serialized as n-times a byte array (that is always prepended with a short indicating its length) containing the serialized value of your key element and a closing 0. It's unclear to me what these closing zeros are for. Has something to do with SuperColumns...

Comment: Nice. We have composite primary keys so this wouldn't quite work but is enough to test the basic hashing is correct. Do you know how cassandra internally hashes a composite key. Looked through your driver and still can't quite work it out.
Btw the inital purpose of this post is now obsolete. I was intending to extend cassandra-sharp with a proper token aware endpoint strategy but I'm now using your CqlSharp driver which has it built in. Thanks!

Comment: It took a deep-dive into the [Cassandra source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cassandra/cassandra-all/1.2.2/org/apache/cassandra/db/marshal/CompositeType.java/), from which I distilled the following: A composite partition key is serialized as n-times a byte array (that is always prepended with a short indicating its length) containing the serialized value of your key element and a closing 0. It's unclear to me what these closing zeros are for. Has something to do with SuperColumns...